# JSF2 and GAE: Passing parameter with Method Expression

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2, el

I followed the tutorial by [Google](https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/sun-javaserver-faces-reference-implementation/configuring-jsf-20-to-run-on-the-google-appengine) and included `el-api-2.2.jar` and `el-impl-2.2.jar` to `WEB-INF/lib`. My test case is simple:

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
  <h:form id="f1">
    <p:commandLink action="#{parameterBean.test(myString)}">
      <h:outputText value="test"/>
    </p:commandLink>
  </h:form>
</f:view>
```

The action method is just a `public void test(String s) {log.log(Level.INFO, "T: "+s);}`. I The log shows (during initial rendering of the page):

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /jsf/admin/test/parameter.xhtml
@15,62 action="#{parameterBean.test('myString')}" Error Parsing:
#{parameterBean.test('myString')}
...
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{parameterBean.test('myString')}
...
Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "(" "( ""
at line 1, column 21.
  Was expecting one of: "}" "." "[" ">" ...
```

I think this error is GAE specific and I'm wondering where `org.apache.el.parser` comes into the game, since the el-libs provide the following packages:

- `el-api-2.2.jar`: `javax.el.*`
- `el-impl-2.2.jar`: `com.sun.el.*`

**Note** During investigation of this problem I checked the [Unified Expression Language web site](https://uel.dev.java.net/) (given in the tutorial) again and only found `el-api-1.1.jar` and `el-impl-1.1.jar` as the latest versions. The error stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `jboss-el.jar' for that purpose

Here.. take a look at issue opened on google about it

[Inability to use EL API 2.2](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3431#c10)

> just put jboss-el.jar (of jboss seam 2) in the lib folder
>
> and add this line in your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

can't find the direct link to jar at the moment... I guess a bit of googleing required

found this for now.... http://www.seamframework.org/Seam2/Downloads

**Edit**

Just noticed its an old thread...

anyway I think you can get the right one from here [Download jboss-el.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjbosseljar.htm)

Comment: this works for me on localhost. i cannot get this working on deployment though!

Comment: make sure that you did deploy the proper jar. and make sure that you are running the updated version of your app (try killing previous sessions etc') if wont help try asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the web application servlet class loader loads the classes in the following order:

1. WEB-INF/classes
2. WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
3. other classes from the servlet container.

Unfortunately, for security reasons, Google has a messed up non Servlet conformant class loader on their GAE, and their classes have priority over the classes you might have in the jars from your WEB-INF/lib or your own WEB-INF/classes.

Since GAE bundles EL 1.1 you are stucked with it until google decides to update their GAE version - don't hold your breath though.